# How to implement many to many relationship in mongoDb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a photography blog, in which I need to store images according to the tags provided by the user. I tried googling and came up with implementing a many to many relationship in mongoDb , but I am still confused as how to take multiple inputs from the user and store them separately . I tried something like this but I don't know how to proceed further.

This is my picture model:-

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const snapSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   Caption: {
        type: String,
        required: "Caption cannot be blank."
   },
   image: String,
   imageId: String,
   author: {
      id: {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "User"
      },
      username: String
   },
    tags: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Tag"
        }
    ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Snap", snapSchema);
```

This is my tag model:-

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const tagSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text: String,
    snaps: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Snap"
        }
    ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Tag", tagSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you think about it, usually an **Image** can have multiple **Tags**, not the other way around. I wouldn't associate **Images** with **Tags** directly. If you want to present images tag-wise, you simply filter your images by tags associated with them. So, your `Snap` model is perfect, but your `Tag` does not need association with any `Image` (it can live without an image, right?).

For presentation purposes, you do a simple filter:

```
Order.find( { tags: your_tag_id } )
```

Here's a great example of how to query by array content: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/

As for your `update` scenario, I imagine that user can input multiple tags for a single image, right? In that case, you simply insert relevant tag ids to `tags` image field.

Comment: Can you tell me how to take multiple separate inputs ?(like when we are writing tags in stackoverflow it automatically make a tag separate once we press spacebar)

Comment: Maybe attach to input's 'on change' event and split by whitespace.